# Calculating Conditional Probability (Maybe using Bayes Theorem)

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Well, I've a bunch of variables, *viz* $Age$, $Gender$, etc..

Age can take: values from $1$ to $6$ (which are actually coded)
Gender can take: $0$ and $1$

I  know the $$P(A=1),...,P(A=6), ... P(G=0), P(G=1)$$

Similarly, I also know $$P(A=1|G=0) , ... , P(A=6|G=0) , ... , P(A=1|G=1) , ... , P(A=6|G=1)$$ and vice versa, for all variables.

Suppose I now change the probability of the variable Age, (still maintaining that $P(A=1) + ... + P(A=6) = 1$. Now, I want that change to affect the probability of $P(G=0)$ and $P(G=1)$, how do I do that?

Comment: Well, unless $P(A\mid G)$ remains the same (and describes the system), changing $P(A)$ won't affect $P(G)$. There are still as many boys and as many girls, they just have a different age.

Comment: I think you should say what it means to "change the Age probabilities".  If all you mean is "the sample doesn't change, we got all the genders right but we used the wrong ages" then I agree with Demosthene, the Gender probabilities should be unchanged.  But if you mean that "we changed the sample and the new sample had a different age profile" then things might be different (especially if, for some reason, Age and Gender turned out not to be independent in the pool from which you are drawing).

Comment: But let's say I changed all the probabilities of $P(A)$, Then How do I calculate $P(A=1|G=0, G=1)$? Maybe this is the correct question. // @lulu Demosthene

Comment: @Demosthene See the comment above? also: maybe I should've introduced prior and posterior probabilities, What I mean to say is: I've prior probabilities (individual and conditional) calculated from statistics and want to infer the probabilities given different set of probabilities.

Comment: How can you change the probabilities in a fixed sample? Suppose, for example, that the variable A (instead of Age) was highly gender correlated.  In an extreme case let's say that knowing A determined gender.  Then if you say "I changed the A probabilities" then you definitely changed the gender probabilities.

Comment: Here's a different thought experiment:  In scenario #1 suppose you remove all the 6 year old boys.  Then you definitely changed both Age and Gender probabilities (unless you had only boys or only  6 year olds from the start).  In scenario #2 suppose you remove a group of 6 year olds in the same gender ratio that holds for the entire sample.  Then you changed the age ratios but you didn't change the gender ratio.

Comment: @lulu, maybe my real question was:  I've prior probabilities (individual and conditional) calculated from some statistics and want to infer the probabilities given different set of probabilities of *some* variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26707/discussion-between-cipher-and-lulu).